# Changing the content of my adapter

Tags: android

I've got a ListView in my `activity` that is initially set to some `Adapter`. Then, after a certain button is clicked, I simply call `listView.setAdapter(new DifferentAdapter(this, foo));`

Seems to work just fine at first. The UI is updated and all is well. Then eventually, it crashes and the log shows me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29724): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
```

I'm guessing it's not so simple to simply call `setAdapter`() whenever you want. Do I need `notifyDataSetChanged` or something? If it matters, I'm not using a `ListActivity`.

**EDIT**

Clarification from below: It's pretty straightforward. I have two inner classes in my Activity, each of which extends BaseAdapter. So I've got two different Adapters and at some point I simply want to switch the ListView to use a different Adapter.

Comment: Are you using any thread or AsyncTask in your activity and in background you are trying to setAdapter ?

Comment: @sat. No. It's pretty straightforward. I have two inner classes in my Activity, each of which extends BaseAdapter. So I've got two different Adapters and at some point I simply want to switch the ListView to use a different Adapter.

Comment: The point where you switch might be important. Before you set the adapter for the second time, use notifyDataSetChanged() and then set Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works fine:

```
listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, mList));
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: creating of new adapter is very bad desigion